# Make question about Java MaxHeapSize more focused

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-request

[This question](https://superuser.com/q/1521631/) about Java MaxHeapSize was closed because it needs to be more focused. How can it be made more focused?

"Needs more focus" is defined [here](https://superuser.com/help/closed-questions) as "has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct)". However, this is not the case. I ask for the list of things that influence MaxHeapSize. That's one answer - a list of things. Could be a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

Comment: “ I'd be able to determine which of the possible reasons“ - This is precisely the reason your question was too broad.  Besides the variables that are responsible for the size of the Java VM heap is well documented.

Comment: @Ramhound documented where? what are these variables? please help!

Comment: [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html) provides a list of every supported Java VM parameter